# NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent() throws "Activity does not have a parent activity name specified."

Tags: android, navigation, android-support-library

When trying to provide up navigation, despite of having set the parentActivityName, and the meta tag for supporting up navigation in older platforms, the support library throws the error `"Activity SecondaryActivity does not have a parent activity name specified."`.

```
        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <activity
                android:name=".app.MainActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name=".app.SecondaryActivity"
                android:parentActivityName=".app.MainActivity" >
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".app.MainActivity" />
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's recommended to use fully qualified component names to refer to parent activities. When using relative component names, the support library tries to infer the full name using the package name.

This is a problem when the package name is overriden. For instance, I was overriding the package name in the `build.gradle`, using `com.mobile.app.development` as the package name for a `development` build flavour.

As a result, the component name inferred was `com.mobile.app.development.app.MainActivity`, which does not exist, instead of `com.mobile.app.MainActivity`.

Comment: Thank you! I would never have figured that out.